# ARKitのARSCNViewに配置された3Dオブジェクトが２つあり、World座標がわかっている場合、この２つの距離を計算したときに出力される値の単位はなんでしょうか。

Tags: swift, ios, arkit

センチメートルなど距離の単位になるのでしょうか。

ARSCNViewで、ARFaceAnchorを検知するようにして、メッシュ頂点の3Dオブジェクト座標を得ることができました。
これをカメラ座標系に変換できれば、Z軸の値は、センチメートルなどの距離になるのかなと疑問に思っています。

色々調べてはいたのですが、カメラ座標に変換するよりも、カメラ自体のワールド座標を得る記事が多くみられました。
そこで考えたのは、メッシュ頂点とカメラの距離をワールド座標で計算すると、センチメートルなどの距離になるのかなと思いました。

僕の考えはあっていますでしょうか。